# Cannot render @Html.PasswordFor correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We recently switched frameworks from MVC 3 to MVC 5. For reasons I don't know it's unable to render password input fields. This is the code

This is the Model code

```
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "New User Password")]
[MinLength(8, ErrorMessage = "Password length must at least 8 characters long.")]
[Required]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

This is the View code

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { id = "tbPassword", @class = "validateMe"})
```

This is the rendered HTML

```html
<input class="validateMe" 
       data-val="true" 
       data-val-minlength="Password length must at least 8 characters long." 
       data-val-minlength-min="8" 
       data-val-required="The New User Password field is required." 
       id="tbPassword" 
       name="User.Password" 
       type="password" 
       style=" background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; 
               background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%;">
```

This is the error in the console.

[image]

What I've tried is removing the name attribute of the element but after that the submit is not working anymore.

Comment: Check the Model. It should return `name='Password'` instead of `name='User.Password'`

Comment: @GauravKP Why would that be? `User.Password` is completely correct if `User` is a property inside the actual ViewModel

Comment: @GauravKP `User` is a property of another class so `User.Password` is correct

Answer (score 0):

I just tested creating a new ASP.NET MVC 5 project to confirm my comment. These are the dependencies that Visual Studio (2017) downloads automatically:

- jQuery 3.3.1
- jQuery Validation 1.17.0
- jQuery Unobtrusive Validation 3.2.4

So, your packages *are* extremely old. Update them for the built-in libraries to work properly.

Comment: can you provide me links for those files? Im doing google but not sure if im on the correct pages